# Function that stores how many iterations it's taken for a Math.Random() to reach 20

Tags: function, loops, math

.move is a Math.random() method in an object
After hitting the first object in my array my loop stops, the function works for that object but does not continue to the next 4 objects...

````
  let turns = [];
  let count = 0 ;
  let steps = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   if (steps <= 20 ){
    steps += arr[i].move();
    count++;
    } else { turns.push(count);
}
}return turns
};```
````

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please reformat the code so it includes all the necessary code (the header of the function is absent), and fix the indentation. Also, include a example of an input, along with the expected output and the actual output.